# Empty files in directory

Tags: php, file, file-io

I am trying to simply empty all the files in a directory, but I keep getting an error that the path in file_put_contents is a directory.

```
      //empty the cache
      $files = scandir('tmp/whazzup/cache/');
      if($files!=false){
           foreach($files as $file){
                file_put_contents('tmp/whazzup/cache/'.$file, '');
           }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP `scandir` returns an array of all files **and directories**. So you are getting an array with elements like `.` and `..` and any other sub-directories.

What you should probably do in your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // ignore directories
    if (is_dir($file)) {
        continue;
    }

    // process files
    file_put_contents(...);
}
```